# Find linked DOM nodes by path with JsViews

Tags: javascript, json, jsrender, jsviews

Is there an easy way to find DOM nodes in the property path of the linked JS object?

For exmpale I have some object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        model = {
            companyName : "JS Corporation",
            address : "",
            staff : [
                {
                    name : "Jack Brown",
                    position : "SW developer"
                },
                {
                    name : "John Dow",
                    position : "Big Boss"
                },
                {
                    name: "Billy Hill",
                    position : ""
                }   
            ]
        } 

    </script>
```

and template

```
    <!-- TEMPLATE -->
    <script  type="text/x-jsrender" id='companyTamplate'>
        <p>company name  <input data-link='companyName'></p>
        <p>address <input data-link='address'></p>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Staff</legend>
            {^{for staff}}
                <div class='person'>
                    <p> name     <input data-link='name'>     </p>
                    <p> position <input data-link='position'> </p>
                </div>
            {{/for}}
        </fieldset>

    </script>
```

and link them

```
$.templates('#companyTamplate').link('#companyView',model);
```

Then I send my object as JSON to a server and get a validation error like this

```
{
    errors : [
        {
            "path" : "address",
            "error" : "empty string"
        },
        {
            "path" : "staff[2].position",
            "error" : "empty string"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to highlight the input field for address and postion. 
For highlighting the address field i can just navigate to 
    input[data-link=address]

But when I have an error in some array member it's not so evident.

Workaround is to add in input field an attribute with a full path

```
<input data-link='position' data-link-path='staff[{{:#index}}].position' >
```

and then navigate to

```
input[data-link-path="staff[2].position"]
```

But it's easy to forget add the additional attribute.

Is there a more simple way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is not necessarily a one to one mapping from data node to views or DOM nodes. You could have one to none, or one to many (for example if you had two {^{for staff}} tags in your template).

But if you are able to use knowledge of the template structure, then you can navigate the view hierarchy and use APIs such `$.view()` `view.contents()` `view.childTags()` to get from the data back to a chosen element on which you want to act programmatically.

For example in your sample, the following gets the jQuery object for the "Billy Hill" 'position' input:

```
$.view().get(true, "array").views[2].contents(true, 'input[data-link="position"]')
```

If you had two {^{for staff}} blocks and you want to navigate to elements in the second block, you can use childTags() APIs to get to the second one:

```
$.view().childTags("for")[1].tagCtx.contentView.views[2].contents(true, 'input[data-link="position"]')
```

which again gets you to the "Billy Hill" 'position input'.

See [View Hierarchy](https://www.jsviews.com/#views), [$.view()](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsv.d.view) and the various [view object](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvviewobject) and [tag object](https://www.jsviews.com/#jsvtagobject) APIs.

Comment: Thanks for answer! It seems it's no so easy to convert strings like "staff[2].position" to expressions like $.view().get(true, "array").views[2].contents(true, 'input[data-link="position"]')

Comment: `$.view()` is the top-level view. You have an array iteration `{{for staff}}` - so `staff[n]` maps to getting the nth item view under the `{{for staff}}` array. That is `.get(true, "array").views[n]`. `.position` maps to `contents(true, 'input[data-link="position"]')`. Really it is just string concatenation inserting the `2` and the `"position"`....